# Arduino W5500 Ethernet GET frame

Tags: c, arduino

I am working on a project to send the values ​​of a temperature and humidity sensor to a server via a GET.

The line in the library of W5500 is:
client.println ("GET / search? q = arduino HTTP / 1.1");

So I change the / search? Q = arduino by the frame I have to send on my database.

The problem is that I can not create my frame. In this frame I have two values ​​uint16_t (Temperature and humidity) and I need to separate them by a "_" to differentiate and parse the frame in my php.

But that's how to change the "GET / search? Q = arduino HTTP / 1.1" by a variable, and how to build a frame with integers and a "_"?!

I have already try strcpy, but strcpy work only with a char or string.

Comment: how exactly should your result string (frame) look?

Comment: Why not send them as separate arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `sprintf`

`sprintf (str, "%d_%d", temp, humid);`